# Triggering Multi Branch Pipeline Jenkins job using the git webhook not working

Tags: jenkins

I have a multi branch pipeline job that is configured like this:

[image: Job Config]

Polling is also configured for it:

[image: Poll Config]

When new commits are pushed to its configured Git repo, after polling, the Job is triggered as expected. In the console output the Git repo is logged as `https://stash.example.com/scm/eg/project.git`.

However when I try to trigger the job using the git notifyCommit webhook, I get this error message:

```
$ curl 'http://jenkins.example.com/git/notifyCommit?url=https://stash.example.com/scm/eg/project.git'
No git jobs using repository: https://stash.example.com/scm/eg/project.git and branches:
No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for: https://stash.example.com/scm/eg/project.git
```

What is missing here? Why Jenkins cannot find any jobs/git consumers for this repo to trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is that you are using BitBucket Plugin in your job configuration so you can't you get notify endpoint to trigger builds using curl request. Also, GitNotify endpoint is part of Github plugin which scans all the job configuration which has used GitPlugin and then it cross-matched the URL of the curl request with the URL od repo used in git plugin. So, If you want to use bitbucket then follow the Instruction Documented on https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381419546/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin